# What is the complexity of these two funtions with respect to input size of integer

Tags: python, time-complexity

1. Assume that given a number n, our function iterates n times. What is its complexity with respect to the input size assuming all the other operations are constant-time? Why?
   My answer: O(2^n), where n is the size of input, size of input = log2n, iterates n times so 2^n
2. Assume that given a number n, our function iterates n**2 times. What is its complexity with respect to the input size assuming all the other operations are constant-time? Why?
   My answer: O(2^ (2^n)), where n is the size of input, size of input = log2n,

I am not sure I understand the questions correctly especially for question2. Is my answers correct for both questions?

Comment: Where are you getting 2^n from? The first one is just O(n) since that's the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

If all operations within the iterations are are constant time, time complexity is just the number of iterations. So the first case is `O(n)`, and the second case is `O(n**2)`.